# SSLRequire multiple OU validation

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, ssl-certificate

We are using client certificates with multiple OU fields. For example:

OU1= ZZZ(unique value)
OU2= XYZ(dynamic value)
OU3= ABC(dynamic value)

I need to write a rule only if the OU3 matches with the client certs that would allow the client to access the server.
Since OU1 and OU2 is dynamic,I cannot use those values directly into this expression %SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_OU in {("ZZZ","XYZ","ABC")}

I also found out in some of the forum to specify the different OU value(%SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_OU_0) and I've tried this by editing the ssl_engine_kernel.c but it didn't work.

I've searched and tried many different
SSLRequire constructions but none of them was successful. Hope someone
can shed some light on this.

Thanks in advance.